# LND describegraph and getnetworkinfo RPC response

Tags: json-rpc, lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

The LND API documentation is [here](http://api.lightning.community), but doesn't contain much information about what the responses to various calls mean. Can anyone explain what these responses are describing?

**describegraph['edges']**

*I understand this to be channel data, but not sure exactly what it's describing.*

- "time_lock_delta": 14,
- "min_htlc": "0",
- "fee_base_msat": "546000"
- "fee_rate_milli_msat": "10"

**getnetworkinfo**

- "avg_out_degree": 2.841628959276018
- "max_out_degree": 102

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the code and running some tests I think I've found the answers:

- **avg_out_degree** is the average channels per node. In other words, total channels / total nodes = avg_out_degree. [source](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/4f91b66c51d0c8e06d3a74579b9c8d26c512ea8e/rpcserver.go#L2677)
- **max_out_degree** is the maximum channels (sum of incoming and outgoing) found on a node in the network. This can be found by iterating through every node and summing their incoming/outgoing channels to find the maximum. [source](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/4f91b66c51d0c8e06d3a74579b9c8d26c512ea8e/rpcserver.go#L2677)
- **time_lock_delta**: the required timelock delta for HTLCs forwarded over the channel. [source](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/e7530787412fb7ffc40bf43e464f3936a9f3c24f/lnrpc/rpc.swagger.json#L1832)
- **min_htlc**: the minimum value in millisatoshi required for incoming HTLCs on the channel. [source](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/e7530787412fb7ffc40bf43e464f3936a9f3c24f/lnrpc/rpc.swagger.json#L1596)
- **fee_base_msat**: the base fee charged regardless of the number of milli-satoshis sent. [source](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/e7530787412fb7ffc40bf43e464f3936a9f3c24f/lnrpc/rpc.swagger.json#L1822)
- **fee_rate_milli_msat**: the effective fee rate in milli-satoshis. The precision of this value goes up to 6 decimal places, so 1e-6. [source](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/e7530787412fb7ffc40bf43e464f3936a9f3c24f/lnrpc/rpc.swagger.json#L1827)